# Assign to *this in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose I have a class `Foo`:

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::string s) noexcept : bar(std::move(s)) {}

    // version 1
    Foo(int x) noexcept
    {
        // do something...
        std::string s = // ...to get a string from `x`
        *this = Foo(std::move(s));
    }

    // version 2
    Foo(int x) noexcept
        : Foo([x] {
            // do something...
            std::string s = // ...to get a string from `x`
            return Foo(std::move(s));
        }())
    {}

private:
    std::string bar;
};
```

Version 1 has cleaner code, but has two disadvantages: 1) if default initialization of the members is expensive, or if there are const members, this version will not work; 2) **is assigning to `*this` in constructor safe?** I have this question because I'm worried the object might be in some "incomplete" state before the constructor returns.

Comment: You have C++11 so why not use a delegating constructor?

   `Foo(int x) : Foo(std::to_string(x)) {}`

Comment: @kfsone The idea of version 2 is just that. I could have returned a string directly in this case, but in the real code the delegated constructor takes more than one arguments, so I have to delegate to the move constructor instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  By the time your constructor body starts running, all the fields have been initialized and the object is valid to assign to.  (Assuming your assignment operator doesn't rely on any preconditions established later in the constructor body, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple:

```
    Foo(int x) noexcept : Foo(getString(x)) { }

private:
    std::string getString(int x) { // make it static if possible
        // do something...
        return // ...get a string from `x`
    }
```

Comment: is calling instance method safe before calling delegated constructor?

Comment: I think you want `getString` to be `static`.

Comment: @5gon12eder If possible, yes.

Comment: It should be `static` (or a free function) because it would not be allowed to use the members of `*this` at this point (except for a handful of operations like taking their address)

Answer (score 1):

`*this = Foo(std::move(s));` means `operator=( Foo(std::move(s)) );`, and you are allowed to call functions from the constructor.

The only issue I see is that all of this string construction may throw an out of memory exception which would terminate the program.  Although maybe consider that if the class is developed in future to be more complicated, problems could arise.

A small issue is that this code initializes `bar` to empty string and then assigns a string.  It would be better to initialize `bar` with the value you want the string to hold, e.g.:

```
Foo(int x) noexcept: bar( calculate_string(x) ) {}
```

where you can write a function `calculate_string` that returns the value for `bar`.